# Why no yellow in powershell and posh git

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

Ok, so in git bash this cmd..

```
git log --pretty='%C(yellow)%h%Creset %s' --abbrev-commit
```

gives me a yellow commit id and white subject line, but in powershell (with posh git) I get no yellow commit id (it's the default white).

Why ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out PowerShell's console renders `System.ConsoleColor.DarkYellow` as white:

```
[Enum]::GetValues([ConsoleColor]) | %{ Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $_ }
```

Using `bold yellow` instead, which renders with `System.ConsoleColor.Yellow`, works:

```
git log --pretty='%C(bold yellow)%h%Creset %s' --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: cygwin and 
color.diff auto
color.status auto
color.branch auto
color.interactive true

Comment: @Klas I'm not sure what you mean? posh-git colors can be configured by setting @GitPromptSettings properties, but by default all yellow colors are `Yellow` not `DarkYellow`.

Comment: My bad. I was thinking of git output, like the hashes in "git reflog", but that is not posh-git's fault of course. I guess I have to look through the git-config(1) man page to find all the color settings that are set to yellow in windows.

Comment: Honestly, I would just start hosting PowerShell in Console2 or ConEmu which use a more standard (and easily customizable) color palette.